# Periodic scheduled toastnotification UWP

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp

I would like to create periodic tost notifications but I found an incorrect solution because snoozeInterva is just a "postponement".

The code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    const string TOAST = @"
                        <toast>
                          <visual>
                            <binding template=""ToastTest"">
                              <text>Hello Toast</text>
                            </binding>
                          </visual>
                          <audio src =""ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail"" loop=""true""/>
                        </toast>";

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnNotification_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var when = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(6);
        var offset = new DateTimeOffset(when);

        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(TOAST);
        ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, offset, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60), 5);
        toast.Id = "IdTostone";
        toast.Tag = "NotificationOne";
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
    }
}
```

Then.. How can I create periodical toast notifications, for example every day at 13:00?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no convenient way to do this. If you need to send a toast every day at the same time, you could schedule a bunch of toast notifications for, let's say, a month upfront, one for each day. And then if you need to change the time of the day for all those toasts, you remove them all from the toast schedule using the `ToastNotificationManager` class and create new scheduled toasts with the right time.

Something like this:

```
    private void ScheduleToast(DateTime scheduledTime)
    {
        const string TOAST = @"
                    <toast>
                      <visual>
                        <binding template=""ToastTest"">
                          <text>Hello Toast</text>
                        </binding>
                      </visual>
                      <audio src =""ms-winsoundevent:Notification.Mail"" loop=""true""/>
                    </toast>";

        Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument xml = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument();
        xml.LoadXml(TOAST);

        ScheduledToastNotification toast = new ScheduledToastNotification(xml, scheduledTime);
        toast.Id = "IdTostone" + scheduledTime.ToString();
        toast.Tag = "NotificationOne";
        toast.Group = "MyEverydayToasts";
        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().AddToSchedule(toast);
    }

    private void RescheduleToastsForTheNextDays(TimeSpan timeOfDay, int nDays = 30)
    {
        ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
        IReadOnlyList<ScheduledToastNotification> scheduledToasts = toastNotifier.GetScheduledToastNotifications();
        foreach(ScheduledToastNotification toast in scheduledToasts)
            toastNotifier.RemoveFromSchedule(toast);

        for (int i=0; i<nDays; i++)
        {
            DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.Today + timeOfDay + TimeSpan.FromDays(i);

            if (scheduledTime > DateTime.Now)
                ScheduleToast(scheduledTime);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would like to ask a question even if a bit banal ... Do you like the windows time app, repeating the weekday alarm is structured this way? I ask him to clarify the ideas. Thanks for help..